# Naming rule for querystring parameters

Tags: querystringparameter

I was wondering if there are any rules or guidlines to name querystring parameters

Currently I use big names that are quite understandable to non-technical users also like

View=AcceptInvitation

Task=JoinTeam

etc.

But when I see querystring parameters used by google, yahoo etc. they are quite small, even sometimes of single letter.

So do they follow some rule to hide the meaning of parameters from user? Something that a developer should follow

Answer (score 0):

You can use any urlencoded string as a querystring parameter, it's only a matter of "flavours". Apparently Google takes into account the first url parameter for displaying search results, so if you're interested in indexing you probably should use meaningful querystring parameters. Google and Yahoo obviously aren't interested in those silly things...